# How can we customize the local account sign-in page as part of an "edit profile" policy in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

The "edit profile" policy has 3 possible page customizations exposed through the Azure portal:

[image]

When invoking this policy, the first page displayed to the user is the IdP selection page. If, on this page, the user chooses the "local account" identity provider, the next page shown is a local account sign-in page.

This sign-in page has the default Microsoft branding, and since it's not listed in the customization blade, I don't know how to customize it:

[image]

How can we customize the UI of this local account sign-in page when it's shown as part of the "edit profile" policy?

Answer (score 1):

A new user journey SignInV2 is in private preview. This will be fully customizable signin user journey. The user journey can be tried from https://aka.ms/b2cnewportal

For local account opt-in to signinv2, please mail to aadb2cpreview@microsoft.com

**EDIT**
A ProfileEdit V2 user journey will also be rolled out soon. That would be fully customizable.

Comment: This sounds promising, but I don't understand how it relates to the "edit profile" policy that I am trying to customize. Does the "edit profile" policy somehow share the sign-in page of the "sign in" policy, even though I have not created any "sign in" policy?

Comment: I am sorry, I missed the profile edit part. Actually ProfileEdit user journey inherits from SignIn user journey. There are also plans for ProfileEditV2 user journey. This should be out anytime soon. This ProfileEdit user journey will be fully customizable as well. I have edited the answer .

Comment: OK, that sounds even more promising. So just to clarify if I understand this correctly:
- there will be new v2 versions of both "sign in" and "edit profile" policies
- these v2 policies will be fully customizable
- we will be able to customize also the local account sign-in page as part of the ProfileEditV2 policy (currently this is not possible)
Remaining questions:
- Will there be a v2 version of "sign-in or sign-up" combined policy too?
- Will we be able to customize the "local account sign-in" page as part of the ProfileEditV2 journey, or must this be customized as part of another?

Comment: ProfileEdit is about to come. signinv2 is already in rollout - if you want it sooner, please send email to aadb2cpreview@microsoft.com.  SusiV2 is already there on the above link - please try it.V2 user journeys have age gating features as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the B2C tenant, you cannot change the Microsoft branding in the "edit profile" policy.

[image]

From the shown picture, in the Page UI customization, you can only change the custom page URI, there is no option to change the company branding.

If you want to change the company branding, you can make it in **Company Branding**.

[image]

Comment: I don't want to change company branding, I want to provide a custom URL. The problem is that the "edit profile" type policy does not contain any page customization section for the local account sign-in that is displayed as part of the flow.

Comment: For now, the Azure B2C has no this feature in the "edit profile". Later if there is the new update for this, I will update the new solution here.